# run terminal commands in spyder ipython console

Tags: python, ipython, ros, gazebo-simu

i have a python script and when I run it in ubuntu terminal it makes my robot to go forward in gazebo simulator. I also have some codes which I have written in  spyder. I want to run that gazebo commands from my spyder ipython console, but when I'm writing the codes that I ran successfully in standard terminal, spyder gives me invalid syntax error. actually I want to know how I can run a gazebo python code in my spyder console.

file:///home/niloofar/Desktop/Screenshot%20from%202019-11-03%2021-07-43.png

This is the picture of terminal which I can run my code in :

file:///home/niloofar/Desktop/Screenshot%20from%202019-11-03%2021-06-31.png

Comment: Please instead of  "pictures" post the code and the errors.

Comment: 1.py is the script that i want to run it from spyder(i can run it by python 1.py in my system terminal), and below is my code in spyder when i wanted to call this script in my spyder and run it from spyder note book :                             !python /home/niloofar/Desktop/1.py                                                                                                    and the error is  :
                                                                      File "/home/niloofar/Desktop/untitled0.py", line 1
    !python /home/niloofar/Desktop/1.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax